# while launching spyder , spyder kernel is showing this error. and anaconda is also not installing other environments

Tags: anaconda, spyder

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1223, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
File "C:\Users\Mahima Kaushik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 309, in start_kernel
kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
File "C:\Users\Mahima Kaushik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 256, in pre_start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "C:\Users\Mahima Kaushik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 468, in write_connection_file
self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
File "C:\Users\Mahima Kaushik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in **enter**
return next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\Mahima Kaushik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 435, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "C:\Users\Mahima Kaushik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 361, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/12040#issuecomment-705033049
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/12040#issuecomment-705057347

I removed the following directory to fix my problem:

C:\Users\Mahima Kaushik\AppData\Roaming\Python